# How can I create extensible reader and writer wrappers around a shared opaque resource class?

Tags: c++, class-design

In C++,
Say I have a `Buffer` class (cannot be inherited) which is given and can support the following operation:

```
class Buffer {
public:
    void write_buffer(Data);
    Data read_next_data();
};
```

Now I want something like `BufferWriter` and `BufferReader`.

There are some requirements:

1. `BufferWriter` should only write but not read the buffer, while
   `BufferReader` should only read the buffer.
2. `BufferWriter` and `BufferReader` should be extendable (can be inherited)
3. A `Buffer` can be shared by multiple `BufferReader`s and `BufferWriter`s
4. I do not want others to use the `Buffer` directly (which the read/write logic has not been separated)

How should I organize the class structure in this case? Or is the requirement contradictory to what is given?

Comment: Is the contents of `Buffer` intended to be a stream? An array? Also, explaining the reasoning behind why you're after this arrangement might help encourage good answers.

Comment: @Dan1701 The buffer is intended to be a stream and different kinds of buffer should read the appropriate data (bytes/packets etc.) from the buffer. I work in a soft real-time industry.

Comment: Make BufferReader and BufferWriter depend on Buffer proxies exposing only one of it's methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the "best" way given these tight constraints, but provided that `Buffer` has separate read/write pointers and works sufficiently on its own through its public interface, you can do like so:

```
class BufferReader
{
public:
    explicit BufferReader(Buffer& ibuf): buf(&ibuf) {}
    virtual ~BufferReader() {}

    virtual int read_int() = 0;
    ...

protected:
    Buffer* buf;
};

class TextBufferReader: public BufferReader
{
public:
    explicit TextBufferReader(Buffer& buf): BufferReader(buf) {}        

    int read_int() override
    {
        // return an integer from 'buf' as a text entry
        // using lexical conversion to an integer.
    }
    ...
};

class BinaryBufferReader: public BufferReader
{
public:
    explicit BinaryBufferReader(Buffer& buf): BufferReader(buf) {}        

    int read_int() override
    {
        // return an integer from 'buf' in binary.
    }
    ...
};
```

... similar idea for `BufferWriter` (with `BufferWriter` calling `write_buffer` and `BufferReader` calling `read_next_data`).

In this case, both `BufferReader` and `BufferWriter` aren't merely extensible (capable of being  inherited). They *need* to be inherited, as this design makes them into abstract base classes. Yet that's probably the most flexible way to go (and also safest since it's not prone to object slicing).

You could also loosen the coupling by making `buf` private and exposing protected methods to read and write from a buffer, e.g. as opposed to a protected data member.

**DIP**

It's worth noting that this design inevitably violates the dependency inversion principle, as we have abstractions depending upon concrete details (`Buffer`) through dependency injection. Yet there are always exceptions to the rule. If your buffer is always some kind of raw buffer of bits and bytes, e.g., and doesn't benefit in the slightest from being abstracted, then it's probably okay to violate DIP in this case as the alternative might make things harder to maintain rather than easier.

**Smart Pointers**

For a safer design, you can use `shared_ptr<Buffer>` instead of a raw pointer, e.g. I'm kind of biased against this in the context of handles that don't need to own memory since I work in a performance-critical field and would prefer to reserve the ability to simply allocate `Buffer` on the stack (especially if you have critical loops that allocate teeny buffers left and right), making it the client's responsibility to ensure that `Buffer` is not destroyed while `BufferReader` and `BufferWriter` are using it. But if performance isn't a pressing goal or if you're willing to tackle efficiency at the memory pool level (possible PITA), then it's definitely a lot safer to use `shared_ptr<Buffer>` here.

In either case, whether through the safer `shared_ptr` which manages the buffer for you or a client-level responsibility to manage `Buffer` manually while using raw pointers, you get the ability to share a single buffer across multiple readers/writers that way.

> I do not want others to use the Buffer directly (which the read/write
>   logic has not been separated)

If you want to enforce this with an iron fist, one way is to make `Buffer` opaque like so:

```
// In some public header:
class Buffer;

// Returns a newly-created buffer for use with BufferReader/BufferWriter subtypes.
std::shared_ptr<Buffer> create_buffer(...);
```

That's all your clients will end up seeing, making it impossible to access the buffer functionality from the outside. In this case, it'd generally be silly *not* to use `shared_ptr`, since the opacity here of this forward-declared type will require a heap (free store) allocation regardless with a custom allocator being the only way to speed things up.

Then `BufferReader` and `BufferWriter` implementations can include a private header which makes the definition of `Buffer` only visible to them. In this case, `shared_ptr<Buffer>` then turns into an opaque handle which can only be passed into a `BufferReader` or `BufferWriter`. Clients cannot do anything with `Buffer` except pass a handle to it along to readers and writers to use.

Comment: +1(later) I like the interesting way how you managed to make the Buffer opaque. Also thanks for reminding me the DIP. It is unfortunate that I have to use the Buffer due to legacy reason.

Answer (score -2):

I understand your design goal.
You can attempt to use Combination model.

Like this as follow:

```
class Buffer {
   public:
      WriterBuffer wb
      ReaderBuffer rb;
 };

 class WriterBuffer{

 };

 class ReaderBuffer{

 };
```

Comment: You didn't format your code quite clearly.
I tried the composition approach (In C++11 outerclass friends the nested class). The problem is, how can I inherit BufferWriter and BufferReader if I use composition approach?